# Rewrite URL post formats (aside, link, gallery, ...) of Wordpress (translate slugs)

Tags: wordpress, seo

I use WordPress in spanish language, and i like to have permalinks in spanish. It's more semantic for spanish users.

In *settings* > *permalinks* is possible to change "*category base*" ("category," by default) and "tag base" ("tage," by default). With some plugins, also "author base" and "pagination base" ("page", by default). But, I've changed post format base (type to tipo), but **I don't know how to change slug name of post formats ("aside", "link", "quotes", ... by default)**.

I want to get a **permalink** like "http://domain.com/**tipo/cita**" instead "http://domain.com/**type/quote**" for listing quotes posts.

Thanks.

Comment: Great question.  Have you tried posting it on wordpress.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 0):

I see that @cscean received an answer a few days later, at http://justintadlock.com/archives/2012/09/11/custom-post-format-urls. To change the post format base from type to tipo, he would use

```
add_filter( 'post_format_rewrite_base', 'my_post_format_rewrite_base' );

function my_post_format_rewrite_base( $slug ) {
return 'tipo';
}
```

The author includes a lot more code that finishes answering the permalinks question.